# Error with hyperref and amsbooka when using \chapter*

Tags: hyperref, chapters, amsbook

I seem to be having a conflict with the packages `amsbooka` and `hyperref` that I don't understand.

I'm using the `amsbooka` package so I can add author names to individual chapters, but I don't want the chapters to be numbered. I use `\chapter*[Test]{Test\author{Me}}` but it displays as "[" for the chapter title followed by the text "Test]TestMe" in the body.

But if I use `\chapter` instead of `\chapter*`, there is no error. And if I remove `\hyperref` then there is no error with `\chapter*`.

Below is a minimal working example. I'm using `TeXShop` on a Mac with `TeXLive 2021` in case that's relevant.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{amsbooka}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Minimal worked example}
\author{A person}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter*[Test]{Test\author{Me}}

\chapter[2nd test]{2nd test\author{Also me}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try to load the package after hyperref.

Comment: @WillieWong did you try?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: that was the first thing i tried before trying to figure out what it doesn't work.

Comment: @WillieWong it works for me in the example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: versions? Hyperref I have `2022-02-21 v7.00n` and amsbooka I have `2014/07/11 v2.08`.

Comment: @WillieWong as you can expect I have a current system hyperref 2022-06-20 v7.00s.

Comment: To Patrick: see ^^^  try updating to TeXLive 2022, and then updating `hyperref` to latest release, and load `amsbooka` after `hyperref`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you Ulrike and Willie!